# How to show multiple TextView 'inline' layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

For e.g. I want to show tags to some article (just like we have tags attached with each question on StackOverflow), I would like to show them like this:
[image]

Where the tags can be of variable length and they should span across multiple lines if they can't fit in the given width. I tried out LinearLayout and RelativeLayout but they don't seem to be able handle such 'auto' arrangement scenario. What layout or methodology should I use to achieve this effect?

Comment: ask umcle google for: android flow layout

Comment: set  `android:layout_width=wrap-content` for both `LinearLayout` as well as your `TextView`

Comment: @Rustam That doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requirement is known as FlowLayout and I found couple of solutions as open source libraries to achieve this effect:
[ApmeM/android-flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)
[blazsolar/FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)